# condition in order by oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want use condition in Oracle for exemple "Order by module = 'TEST' last" and get ALL module = 'TEST' in last in my request

thank for help

Comment: Share sample data and the output expected.Also the query you have tried if any.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
select *
from modules
order by case when module = 'Test' then 2 else 1 end, module
```

This puts module 'Test' last and sorts all other orders alphabetically.